# Filter user processes from kernel processes and system daemon

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I need to iterate through all the processes in the system and just get the PID of user processes to kill it. Kernel processes and system daemons must be ignored.

When I use ps command process having PIDs < 1000 are important kernel processes. I don't want to crash the system by killing important processes

```
for_each_process(task) {
    if(task->pid > 999){
       //CODE 
    }
```

By user processes I mean process which the user started like firefox, terminal or any other application. Code is executed as a kernel module. I would be very grateful if someone can help.

Comment: an excerpt from the MAN page for PS:  *By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID
       (euid=EUID) as the current user and associated with the same terminal
       as the invoker.  It displays the process ID (pid=PID), the terminal
       associated with the process (tname=TTY), the cumulated CPU time in
       [DD-]hh:mm:ss format (time=TIME), and the executable name (ucmd=CMD).
       Output is unsorted by default.*  If that is not quite what you want, Read the MAN page for the many other options

Comment: I am trying to do this in a kernel module. I believe PS won't help.

Comment: You mentioned trying to use PS in your question.  You did NOT mention that you are trying to write a kernel module to do this.  That is critical information.  Do NOT leave out critical information

Comment: Yes. Sorry for omitting that. Since for_each_process() is a kernel macro I assumed all would know that it is kernel module.